# Installing neo4j-spatial on neo4j 2.3.1

Tags: maven, neo4j

I cloned the neo4j-contrib/spatial repo on github, but the recommended "mvn install" doesn't work--it breaks on a bunch of missing files and symbols (e.g. "package org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene does not exist").

The pom.xml file in the repo references neo4j 3.0.0, but I'm running neo4j 2.3.1 on Ubuntu 15.04.   Neo4j 3.0.0 is not yet listed as a stable release.

There is a separate repo of releases for neo4j-spatial at neo4j-contrib/m2, including one targeting neo4j-2.3.0, but having cloned the repo, it's not clear whether or how to use this to get the mvn install to work.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which branch are you trying to build? [This branch](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial/tree/0.15-neo4j-2.3) is the release targeting Neo4j 2.3 and should build fine. If you aren't able to build please submit a Github issue with the error(s).

For installing the server plugin there are pre-compiled versions of the JAR files available [here](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial#using-the-neo4j-spatial-server-plugin) that you can just unzip and drop in the `/plugins` directory. The [most recent](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/m2/blob/master/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-spatial/0.15-neo4j-2.3.0/neo4j-spatial-0.15-neo4j-2.3.0-server-plugin.zip?raw=true) targets Neo4j 2.3. This should work fine with Neo4j 2.3.1 (I used this neo4j-spatial release with Neo4j 2.3.1 for a project last week without any problems).

Comment: Thanks William, this works; and thanks for your other posts on spatial!

Comment: I'm having an issue getting the Spatial plugin recognized by Neo4j 2.3.1. Nothing shows under extensions. Where should I open a ticket at?

Comment: @LeviRoberts you can create a SO question or ask on Neo4j public slack channel neo4j.com/slack