# Spatial extension/plugin does not load on Neo4j desktop community edition 2.3.0

Tags: maven, neo4j, spatial

After installing the Spatial plugin and repeating again and again, I still can not get Neo4j to load the extension.

I am using `Neo4j Community Edition 2.3.0` with `neo4j-spatial-0.15-neo4j-2.3.0`

Starting from command line:

```
$:~ levi$ java -jar ./databases/Neo4j\ Community\ Edition\ 2.3.0.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/neo4j-desktop-2.3.0.jar 
2016-01-25 14:05:15.687-0600 INFO  [o.n.s.d.LifecycleManagingDatabase] Successfully started database
2016-01-25 14:05:15.722-0600 INFO  [o.n.s.CommunityNeoServer] Starting HTTP on port 7474 (4 threads available)
2016-01-25 14:05:16.047-0600 INFO  [o.n.s.w.Jetty9WebServer] Mounting static content at /webadmin
2016-01-25 14:05:16.105-0600 INFO  [o.n.s.w.Jetty9WebServer] Mounting static content at /browser
Jan 25, 2016 2:05:16 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'
Jan 25, 2016 2:05:17 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'
Jan 25, 2016 2:05:17 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'
2016-01-25 14:05:17.803-0600 INFO  [o.n.s.CommunityNeoServer] Remote interface ready and available at http://localhost:7474/
```

and using curl:

`curl -v http://neo4j:password@localhost:7474/db/data/`

```
*   Trying ::1...
* connect to ::1 port 7474 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 7474 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'neo4j'
> GET /db/data/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:7474
> Authorization: Basic bmVvNGo6dG93bmVy
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 25 Jan 2016 20:09:03 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Length: 730
< Server: Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT)
< 
{
  "extensions" : { },
  "node" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node",
  "node_index" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node",
  "relationship_index" :     "http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/relationship",
  "extensions_info" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext",
  "relationship_types" :     "http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/types",
  "batch" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/batch",
  "cypher" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher",
  "indexes" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/schema/index",
  "constraints" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/schema/constraint",
  "transaction" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction",
  "node_labels" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/labels",
  "neo4j_version" : "2.3.0"
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

The directory structure looks like this:

```
app/resources/
app/resources/bin/neo4j-desktop-2.3.0.jar
app/resources/plugins/neo4j-spatial-0.15-neo4j-2.3.0
app/resources/plugins/neo4j-spatial-0.15-neo4j-2.3.0/neo4j-spatial-0.15-neo4j-2.3.0.jar
app/resources/plugins/neo4j-spatial-0.15-neo4j-2.3.0/_all_helper_files
```

Related Stack question: [Installing neo4j-spatial on neo4j 2.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474507/installing-neo4j-spatial-on-neo4j-2-3-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this to work by building from source.

`$ brew install maven`

Specifically cloned `0.15-neo4j-2.3` branch.

Compiled/Installed using:
`$ mvn install`

Copied the directory named `neo4j-spatial-0.15-neo4j-2.3.1-server-plugin` directly into the `neo4j/plugins` directory.

Started up server then:
`$ curl -v http://neo4j:password@127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/`

```
{
  "extensions" : {
    "SpatialPlugin" : {
      "addNodesToLayer" : "http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addNodesToLayer",
      "addEditableLayer" : "http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addEditableLayer",
      "addCQLDynamicLayer" : "http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addCQLDynamicLayer",
      "findGeometriesWithinDistance" : "http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/findGeometriesWithinDistance",
      "updateGeometryFromWKT" : "http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/updateGeometryFromWKT",
      "addGeometryWKTToLayer" : "http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addGeometryWKTToLayer",
      "getLayer" : "http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/getLayer",
      "findClosestGeometries" : "http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/findClosestGeometries",
      "addSimplePointLayer" : "http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addSimplePointLayer",
      "findGeometriesInBBox" : "http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/findGeometriesInBBox",
      "addNodeToLayer" : "http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addNodeToLayer"
    }
  },
  "node" : "http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/node",
  "node_index" : "http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/index/node",
  "relationship_index" : "http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/index/relationship",
  "extensions_info" : "http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/ext",
  "relationship_types" : "http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/relationship/types",
  "batch" : "http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/batch",
  "cypher" : "http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/cypher",
  "indexes" : "http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/schema/index",
  "constraints" : "http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/schema/constraint",
  "transaction" : "http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/transaction",
  "node_labels" : "http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/labels",
  "neo4j_version" : "2.3.0"
}
```

Comment: Missing a slash between `db` and `data` in `$ curl -v http://neo4j:password@127.0.0.1:7474/dbdata/`

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll fix it. Probably just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by the method you are using to start Neo4j. It looks like you are using the Neo4j Desktop application, but starting it from the command line? Did you try starting from the desktop application?

Also, the directory structure might be a bit off. You want the spatial extension jar (and all dependency jars) to be in the root of the `plugins` directory. If you click "options" in the desktop app you will see the default directory for plugins, which can be configured:

[image]

Comment: I am starting the database using the GUI as in your screenshot. However for debugging purposes, I've also provided the output from terminal because I'm unsure of where the logs are located. For completeness sake, I've tried moving all of the jar files into the plugins path, with the same result.